# Attempting copy paste cells from one sheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy column B from sheet called "Activity Overview" (Only filled cells) and paste in a sheet called "V&VFile" in column E from row 11 onwards, however when i run the macro the cells arent copied and seems to paste blank cells.

The source of the data uses excel formula index match, is this why as it can copy the data as its found from an excel formula?

```
Sub VVfileFILL()

Dim Lastrow As Double

Lastrow = Worksheets("Activity Overview").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Activity Overview").Range("B" & Lastrow).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("V&V").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(10, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Your copy line is copying a single cell `"B" & Lastrow`.

Comment: How would i change this

Comment: Well what's the range you want to copy, does it contain formulae and are there blanks you want to miss out? If so, are the blanks also the result of a formula? A screenshot would help.

Comment: Yes it contains formula Index Match to find the values. Its in coloumn B from row 2 all the way to row 62. But if this range changes i want them to be copied as well

Comment: Are the results of the formula either blank or a number OR blank or text?

Comment: Blank or text i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think one can avoid a loop in this situation.

```
Sub VVfileFILL()

Dim Lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long

n = Worksheets("V&V").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(10, 0).Row

With Worksheets("Activity Overview")
    Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To Lastrow
        If Len(.Cells(r, "B")) > 0 Then 'check not blank
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("V&V").Range("E1:E" & n), .Cells(r, "B")) = 0 Then 'check not already in E
                Worksheets("V&V").Cells(n, "E").Value = .Cells(r, "B").Value 'transfer value
                n = n + 1 'add 1 to destination row
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It copies and pastes the correct values, but it pastes them in row 157

Comment: You need to adjust the destination row then. You're offsetting 10 from the last row so you must have data in row 147. If you have a fixed destination range then just start with e.g. `n=2` in the third line.

Comment: Thanks works a treat, is there a way it can check if the value already exists in column and if not insert but if it does skip to next one

Comment: I've added a line to check that above.

Comment: sorry it does work i accidentally missed a line out

Comment: However, if i keep running it, it adds the last row to the column each time. So if 1 was last, it would another 1 in the row below then when i run it again it removes that 1.

Comment: I also think its missing out around 10 cells, would this have something to do with me declaring n = 10 (as i want to start the pasting in 10th row

Comment: If you're running the code repeatedly it will start again at 10 and overwrite.

Comment: which is what i want as i want activities to be able to be added to activity overview and only the new ones be added to the list

Comment: It also skips rows when copying for somereason, around 10 rows.

Comment: You should clear column E at the start of the code to remove any existing entries.

Comment: I have understood why some values arent being copied, there are some tasks that are the same but at different points. So i going to remove the check to see if the same and then just add a clear in so its correct each time

Comment: But again, it clears all columns not just column B, and also removes the standard borders of the grid

Comment: I don't understand why you are clearing column B. As far as my testing allows, the code above does what you ask.

Comment: Sorry i meant Column E in VVfile, yes the code works perfectly but the column E wont clear unless all cleared

Comment: What do you mean by "column E wont clear unless all cleared"? Just put `Worksheets("V&V").Range("E:E").clearcontents` at the start of the code.

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer, for which thanks, so does that mean we've got there?

Comment: YEs we got there! Sorry for being a novice and hard work! works great now thank you! your effort is very much kindly appreciated.

Comment: A question that is a bit off subject, how did you become so proficient in coding especially VBA? Would you recommend any courses etc.

Comment: My employer did send me on a short basic course some years ago, which did help, but there is tons of stuff online - youtube videos etc. I started off with a specific task, asked on forums and built up from there, as you are doing here. It does help if you have an objective. Grasp the basic concepts of the object model and you can build on that too. I am not a programmer really, but have just acquired a fair amount of VBA knowledge and sort of understand what I'm doing without a deep knowledge that some here have.